# How to pivot ntext datatype column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can you please help with the below query as I have to convert the row into the column.

```
select  question,[1],[2],[3],[4] from
(
    select      
        qm.question, cm.choice,  
        cast (row_number() over (partition by question order by question) as nvarchar(max)) as tbl
    from        
        questionm qm, choicem cm 
    where 
        qm.questionID = 1 and cm.questionid = 1) CTE
PIVOT
(
    max(cast((choice) as nvarchar(max)))
    for tbl in ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) tmp
```

The datatype of question and choice is `ntext` and after execution the script is throwing error :

> Msg 488, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
>   Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. The type of column "question" is "ntext", which is not comparable.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. The ntext datatype has been deprecated for almost 15 years now in favor of varchar(max). Time to update your schema. You also should consider using the ANSI-92 style join sytax. It has been available for more than 25 years now. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I assume changing your data type to `nvarchar(MAX)` isn't an option? It's been deprecated since at least SQL Server 2005. Pivoting on an `ntext` column seems odd as well; could you really have something you need to pivot on that has 4001+ characters?

Comment: Try Casting the nText to an NVarchar(Max)

Comment: Thanks all.. we will update the schema.